# split video with bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I can split any video in any folder (home and other folder) with this bash but I think this xdotool and clipboard commands are not standard. Anybody can help me to suggest alternative for xdotool key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> myfn=`xclip -o -selection clipboard` commands. Is it possible to create this bash in another simple way?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1
xdotool key ctrl+c
myfn=`xclip -o -selection clipboard`

frmdata=$(yad --title "Split Vedio" --form --field="File name" --field="Start time" --field="End time" "$myfn"  "000"  "000")
inputStr0=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')
timestart=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $2 }')
timeend=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $3 }')
filename=$inputStr0
file_basename="$(basename "$inputStr0")"

sth="${timestart:0:2}"
stm="${timestart:2:2}"
sts="${timestart:4:2}"
myst="$sth":"$stm":"$sts"

fth="${timeend:0:2}"
ftm="${timeend:2:2}"
fts="${timeend:4:2}"
myft="$fth":"$ftm":"$fts"


ffmpeg -i "$inputStr0" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -ss "$myst" -t "$myft" /media/mymint/LINUXDATA/FDATA/FCRYPTXDATA/WRK/"$file_basename"
```

Comment: What do the "xdotool and clipboard" commands do for you? Until we know that...

Comment: to get the file path and file name